# jquery next () and setInterval ()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Markup:

```
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='item'>1</div>
  <div class='item hidden'>2</div>
  <div class='item hidden'>3</div>
  <div class='item hidden'>4</div>
</div>
```

Code:

```
$('.parent .item').each(function () {
    var current = $(this);
    setInterval(function () {
        $(current).fadeOut(function () {
            $(this).next().fadeIn();
        });
    }, 2000); //rotate every 2 seconds
});
```

I want to show each "item" for 2 seconds and after that fadeOut and fadeIn the next item. When there are no more items then fadeOut and start from the beginning. The code seems like it would work but it is having timing issues and doesn't move automatically through all items.

The hidden class is `display:none`.

Comment: Syntax error, `$(new).fadeOut.function`. Also `new` is a reserved word. Please validate your code prior to asking http://www.jshint.com/.

Comment: The code does not seem to work. Look at [your console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) to see the syntax errors pop up.

Comment: Do you mean to have all 4 items show, and then start to show one at a time? Or show one at a time from the start, alternating every 2 seconds?

Comment: @DaveStein - One item at a time from the start every 2 seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used the fiddle to CSS it so the numbers are overlapping instead of jittering around. Also all items hidden by default.

http://jsfiddle.net/9fXmA/1/

```
var items = $('.parent .item');
var item = items.first();

function cycle() {

  // Take 500 MS to fadeout first    
  item.fadeOut( 500 );

  // Get next item
  item = item.next();

  // When at last item, go to first
  if ( !item || !item.length ) {
    item = items.first();
  }

  // Fadein new item for 500 MS
  item.fadeIn( 500, function() {
     // Wait 1500 MS ( to total 2 seconds ) before bringing in next item
     setTimeout( cycle, 1500 );
  });

}

// Show first item instantly
item.show();

// Wait to seconds before starting to cycle
setTimeout( cycle, 2000 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('.parent .item').each(function(){
  var itm = $(this);
  itm.fadeOut(2000, function(){
    itm.next().fadeIn();
  });
});
```

Comment: A bit of explanation would be better. Don't do other people's homework for them. Instead, help them learn.

Comment: I just thought it was obvious. Sorry if it's not.

Answer (score 1):

This works but it jumps around a lot:

```
$('.parent').find('.item').each(function () {
    var current = $(this);
    setInterval(function () {
        current.fadeOut(function () {
            current.next().fadeIn();
        });
    }, 2000); //rotate every 2 seconds
});
```

What you probably want it to have the sequentially process and not potentially have more than one displayed as this will do, due to the process disjoint based on the `setInterval`.

Comment: Once you've wrapped a native object in `$()` you don't need to wrap it again (although it doesn't hurt it incurs performance cost). Just call `current.fadeOut(...)` directly

Comment: This is still pretty ugly and could be done better IF I had time at the moment.